# Why does relative speed of light when in a non-inertial frame does not increase when viewed from an inertial frame

Tags: reference-frames, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, relative-motion

I mean to ask if I have a moving object and I turn on a bulb in that moving object, when viewed from an inertial frame, we usually add the speed of the moving object with the object's velocity to get its velocity with respect to the inertial frame.

But as I've heard the speed of light remains same in all frames? Why is that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity

Comment: The body of your question doesn’t mention any non-inertial frame. Do you understand what inertial and non-inertial frames are?

Comment: *we usually add…* That’s just a good approximation at low speeds. Until you studied Special Relativity, you didn’t know you’d been doing it wrong.

Comment: @Ghoster sorry for the unclear language, I meant an accelerating frame. But I think I've got my answer, which is special relativity, I'm yet to study it, so I'll look more into it

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't. This fact came as a surprise, forcing physics to revise its models of space and time. In those revised models, the speed of light is the same in all frames, but it is the phenomena that force these models on us. You may sensibly ask "what experiments and observations show that the speed of light is the same in all frames", but there is no "why". It's how the universe works.